# Javaで単品のプログラムの依存性をpipみたいに管理したい

Tags: java, maven

Javaで、Mavenプロジェクトに入っていないような単品のプログラムに対して、
外部のライブラリをいい感じに追加する方法ってありますか？

例えば、以下のように外部ライブラリを使うプログラムで、

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.commons.csv.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Reader fr = new FileReader("ppap.csv");
            Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withHeader().parse(fr);

            for(CSVRecord rec: records){
            System.out.println(rec.get("a"));
            }
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

今はコンパイルを通すため、.jarファイルを手動でダウンロードしています。
コンパイル時・起動時も手動で -classpath を指定しています。

これが面倒なのですが、みなさんはどんな方法を使っていますか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Javaのプロジェクトなら[Maven](http://maven.apache.org)や[Gradle](http://gradle.org)でプロジェクトの依存管理が出来ます。このシステムを利用すると、フォルダー構成が固定になりますので自由度が少しなくなりますが、簡単に依存を追加したり、更新したり出来ますので便利です。

Mavenをインストールしましたら、コマンドから`mvn archetype:generate`を実行し、パッケージ名とJarファイル名を入力すればMavenの設定ファイル（pom.xml)とフォルダー構成が作成されます。（Windowsだとエンターキーをもう一度押す必要ある場合があります。）

```
Choose org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart version:
1: 1.0-alpha-1
2: 1.0-alpha-2
3: 1.0-alpha-3
4: 1.0-alpha-4
5: 1.0
6: 1.1
Choose a number: 6: Define value for property 'groupId': com.example
Define value for property 'artifactId': hogehoge-app
Define value for property 'version' 1.0-SNAPSHOT: :
Define value for property 'package' com.example: :
Confirm properties configuration:
groupId: com.example
artifactId: hogehoge-app
version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
package: com.example
Y: : y
```

その後は`mvn test`で単体テストの実行や`mvn package`でJarファイルを作成する事が出来ます。`package`したら`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.App`を実行すればすべての依存がクラスパスに追加してメインクラスを実行されます。

依存を追加するのに[search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org)から検索し、詳細画面に出る`<dependency>`のXMLをpom.xmlファイルの`<dependencies>`の中に追加するだけです。

Comment: なるほど。私が気になっているのは、プロジェクトを作成するまでもない小さいプログラムです。（例えばライブラリの挙動の調査や、ちょっとした計算など）
そうした場合でも、wm_eddieさんは毎回プロジェクトを作成していますか？

Comment: @hiroga 回答者ではないですが、Javaでプログラム書く時はどんなときでもMavenプロジェクトにしますね。本当にちょっとした調査だけしたいなら、専用のサンドボックス・プロジェクトでも作っておくか、JavaのREPLを使えばいいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: @hiroga ちなみにJavaのREPLは、Java9なら標準でJShellが付いてきますし、それ以前なら https://github.com/albertlatacz/java-repl が使えます。Macをお使いならHomebrewでインストールできます。

Comment: @TadayoshiSato ご助言ありがとうございます。その通りにしてみようと思います。